# Finding the difference of times in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

I have a table with two columns(datatype is varchar2) having timestamps. I want to find the difference of timestamps i.e; timestamp difference between ADDITIONAL_COLUMN2 and ADDITIONAL_COLUMN1.

My table columns :

[image: My columns of the table]

I tried below code but it is giving me error.

```
SELECT (extract(DAY FROM ADDITIONAL_COLUMN2-ADDITIONAL_COLUMN1)*24*60*60)+ 
(extract(HOUR FROM ADDITIONAL_COLUMN2-ADDITIONAL_COLUMN1)*60*60)+
(extract(MINUTE FROM ADDITIONAL_COLUMN2-ADDITIONAL_COLUMN1)*60)+
extract(SECOND FROM ADDITIONAL_COLUMN2-ADDITIONAL_COLUMN1) into diff
FROM Table;
```

> Error: missing keyword.

Query:

```
SELECT (extract(DAY FROM to_timestamp_tz(ADDITIONAL_COLUMN2)-to_timestamp_tz(ADDITIONAL_COLUMN1))*24*60*60)+
(extract(HOUR FROM to_timestamp_tz(ADDITIONAL_COLUMN2)-to_timestamp_tz(ADDITIONAL_COLUMN1))*60*60)+
(extract(MINUTE FROM to_timestamp_tz(ADDITIONAL_COLUMN2)-to_timestamp_tz(ADDITIONAL_COLUMN1))*60)+
extract(SECOND FROM to_timestamp_tz(ADDITIONAL_COLUMN2)-to_timestamp_tz(ADDITIONAL_COLUMN1))
FROM MISIMD_FOM_SPM_AUDIT;
```

[image: output for the query]

Query 2:

```
with cte (diff) as (
  select to_timestamp_tz(additional_column2, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')
       - to_timestamp_tz(additional_column1, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')
       as diff
  from MISIMD_FOM_SPM_AUDIT
)
select (extract(day from diff)*24*60*60)
     + (extract(hour from diff)*60*60)
     + (extract(minute from diff)*60)
     + extract(second from diff) as diff
from cte;
```

This query is giving me the required output.
[Output of Query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeQXV.png)

Comment: You've tagged this a [tag:plsql], but are you actually running it in a PL/SQL block, or as plain SQL? If it's plain SQL then just change 'into' to 'as'.

Comment: Its a plain sql statement. And i changed into to as. I was getting the below error

ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source
30076. 00000 -  "invalid extract field for extract source"
*Cause:    The extract source does not contain the specified extract field.

Comment: [It works with `as`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fddb6debaacb5e9198af2aa11e896867). Assuming they are actually timestamp fields (and your NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ format is applying that formatting); and they are not actually varchar2 strings?

Comment: I am sorry, the columns are of type varchar2 and not time stamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ORA-00905: missing keyword" error is because you have `into` instead of `as`; changing that:

```
... AS diff
```

[now works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fddb6debaacb5e9198af2aa11e896867), but...

> i changed into to as. I was getting the below error ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source

which means your columns aren't actually timestamps, [they're strings](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=71ee3c6f9810228dfc83e86a11ede357), so you need to convert them to actual timestamps first:

```
    with cte (ts1, ts2) as (
      select to_timestamp_tz(additional_column1, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM'),
             to_timestamp_tz(additional_column2, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')
      from your_table
    )
    select (extract(day from ts2-ts1)*24*60*60)
         + (extract(hour from ts2-ts1)*60*60)
         + (extract(minute from ts2-ts1)*60)
         + extract(second from ts2-ts1) as diff
    from cte;
```

or do the calculation in the CTE too:

```
with cte (diff) as (
  select to_timestamp_tz(additional_column2, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')
       - to_timestamp_tz(additional_column1, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM')
       as diff
  from your_table
)
select (extract(day from diff)*24*60*60)
     + (extract(hour from diff)*60*60)
     + (extract(minute from diff)*60)
     + extract(second from diff) as diff
from cte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=19db85fcb0054119955b62a25794482e)

Comment: yes, the code is working fine now. But I am getting null as the output. is it because the time difference between them is small?

Comment: No, a small time difference will still be reported; if the times are the same it will report 0. You'll get null if either column in the table is null. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5229da94a5aef25c499f134d1ea1488c).

Comment: @prudhvibikumalla - in the code you added as an edit to your question, you are doing just `to_timestamp_tz(ADDITIONAL_COLUMN2)` without specifying the format mask. That should error (probably ORA-01858), though it looks like `default null on conversion error` is being applied automatically... Never rely on NLS settings, always explicitly supply the format mask. What do you get if you actually run what's in my answer?

Comment: your version of code worked, it is giving me the difference of the times even it is for 1 second. Thanks a lot. I am adding the output image in the question.

Comment: hi @prudhvibikumalla , please accept the answer if you consider so

Answer (score 0):

I execute the following test case, which obviously uses my own NLS settings:

```
PARAMETER                                VALUE
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION                        12.2.0.1.0
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP                      FALSE
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS                     BYTE
NLS_COMP                                 BINARY
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY                        $
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT                  DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT                       HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT                     DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                          HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_SORT                                 BINARY
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE                        AMERICAN

PARAMETER                                VALUE
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                          DD-MON-RR
NLS_CALENDAR                             GREGORIAN
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS                   .,
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET                   AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET                         AL32UTF8
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY                         AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY                             $
NLS_TERRITORY                            AMERICA
NLS_LANGUAGE                             AMERICAN

SQL> create table my_test ( c1 timestamp , c2 timestamp ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_test values ( systimestamp , null ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> -- I wait for a couple of seconds 
SQL> update my_test set c2=systimestamp ;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> col c1 for a40
SQL> col c2 for a40
SQL> select c1,c2 from my_test ;

C1                                       C2
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
30-JUN-20 11.03.01.262132 AM             30-JUN-20 11.03.16.079616 AM

SQL>  SELECT (extract(DAY FROM c2-C1)*24*60*60)+
  2  (extract(HOUR FROM C2-C1)*60*60)+
  3  (extract(MINUTE FROM C2-C1)*60)+
  4  extract(SECOND FROM C2-C1)
  5* FROM my_test
SQL> /

(EXTRACT(DAYFROMC2-C1)*24*60*60)+(EXTRACT(HOURFROMC2-C1)*60*60)+(EXTRACT(MINUTEFROMC2-C1)*60)+EXTRACT(SECONDFROMC2-C1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                             14.817484

SQL>
```

You cannot put an INTO inside a query, that is PL/SQL, not SQL. Exactly what is the problem here, because your query works for me, as long as I removed the INTO part of it.

**Update Answer**

As your case uses varchar2 for timestamp columns and stores the timezone with it ( which is non sense if you ask me ) the case is different. You need to apply to your query a transformation to convert the varchar2 into a right timestamp.

```
SQL> create table my_test ( c1 varchar2(100), c2 varchar2(100) );

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_test values ( to_char(systimestamp) , null );

1 row created.

SQL> update my_test set c2=to_char(systimestamp) ;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> set lines 200
SQL> col c1 for a50
SQL> col c2 for a50
SQL> select c1,c2 from my_test ;

C1                                                 C2
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
30-JUN-20 11.12.11.094964 AM +02:00                30-JUN-20 11.12.26.082914 AM +02:00
```

Here you can see that the values are stored as varchar2 but with timestamp with time zone format.

```
SQL> select to_timestamp_tz(c1) , to_timestamp_tz(c2) from my_test ;

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(C1)                                                         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(C2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
30-JUN-20 11.12.11.094964000 AM +02:00                                      30-JUN-20 11.12.26.082914000 AM +02:00
```

Now, the same query you use before

```
SQL> SELECT (extract(DAY FROM to_timestamp_tz(c2)-to_timestamp_tz(C1))*24*60*60)+
  2  (extract(HOUR FROM to_timestamp_tz(c2)-to_timestamp_tz(C1))*60*60)+
  3  (extract(MINUTE FROM to_timestamp_tz(c2)-to_timestamp_tz(C1))*60)+
  4  extract(SECOND FROM to_timestamp_tz(c2)-to_timestamp_tz(C1))
FROM my_test;  5

(EXTRACT(DAYFROMTO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(C2)-TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(C1))*24*60*60)+(EXTRACT(HOURFROMTO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(C2)-TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(C1))*60*60)+(EXTRACT(MINUTEFROMTO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(C2)-TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(C1))*60)+EXT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                                                                       14.98795

SQL>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: the datatype of my column is varchar2 and not timestamp. is that why i am getting wrong error?

Comment: I saw that now. my apologies, Building the answer for your case...

Comment: thanks roberto the code is working but i am getting null as output. is it because the difference is that small?

Comment: you got null when both timestamps are not null ? or when the rows are actually null ? in your example, you have some rows with null values. Can you tell me which one is giving you null as result ?

Comment: I was trying to run your query but I just observed i was getting this error.

ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"

Comment: can you run select * from nls_database_parameters to see which kind of NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ format you have ??

Comment: NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT: 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR'. the output for the query you asked

Comment: @prudhvibikumalla - you shouldn't rely on NLS settings for anything except ad hoc queries; someone else running your code later with different settings will get errors or wrong results. It's better to specify the correct format mask, matching the actual strings, as part of the `to_xxx()` function call. This specific error is because Oracle is 'helpfully' interpreting 2020-06 as the 20th day of the 20th month - hence the error message.

Comment: I am agree. You only need to change the TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ function by using your own format stored in your table. TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(c1,'YOURTZFORMAT')